# Add different inheritance objects into tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, inheritance, realm

i've created a SuperClass and two subclasses in Realm. I've then created multiple objects in `Cat` and `Dog`classes. My question is then what is the best solution to retrieve these objects and add them to a tableView. All the information which should be put in the tableView is from the SuperClass? Do i need to retrieve `Dog`and `Cat`individually and merge these arrays? if yes then how can i do it? or what is the best solution in this case?

```
class Pet: Object {
    var myDate = NSDate()
    var title = ""
    var subTitle = ""
}

class Dog: Pet {
}

class Cat: Pet {
}
```

Comment: See my answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32827599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm [doesn't support polymorphic queries yet](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109). So you can't query `realm.objects(Pet)`. But each object of both `Results` can be added to an array, whose Element type is the superclass.

So you would need to query for both object types separately.

```
let cat = realm.objects(Cat)
let dog = realm.objects(Dog)
```

Depending on your use-case, you could just pull them all in memory and append them both to an array of `[Object]` and then simply sort that array.
That would look like below:

```
var pets = [Object]()
pets += dogs.map { $0 as Pet }
pets += cats.map { $0 as Pet }
```